# Text does not follow css transition

Tags: jquery, css, text, transition

I have created this code, but the text does not follow the parent div transition. It works somehow with the overflow property at the text, but it does not create the transition effect; it just appears and disappears.

Maybe I am missing something completely. I don't know why it does not work. Also, with relative and absolute position does not work.

Code:

```js
jQuery('#post-button').click(function() {

  jQuery(this).toggleClass('open-button');
  if (jQuery(".post-content").hasClass("open-post")) {
    jQuery(".post-content").removeClass("open-post");

  } else {
    jQuery(".post-content").toggleClass("open-post");
  }

  if (jQuery(".post-grad").hasClass("open-post")) {
    jQuery(".post-grad").removeClass("open-post");

  } else {
    jQuery(".post-grad").toggleClass("open-post");
  }

  if (jQuery(".text-post").hasClass("open-post")) {
    jQuery(".text-post").removeClass("open-post");

  } else {
    jQuery(".text-post").toggleClass("open-post");
  }

});
```

```css
.post-content {
  height: 0vh;
  width: 80%;
  background: #464646;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.text-post {
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Avenir_Light;
  height: 0vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-post-title {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-family: Avenir_Light;
  height: 0vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-grad {
  width: 80%;
  height: 0vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72));
  position: fixed;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.open-post {
  height: 80vh;
}

#post-button {
  display: inherit;
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#post-button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#post-button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#post-button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
}

#post-button.open-button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="post-button">
  <span></span>
  <span></span> Project Button
</div>
<div class="post-content">
  <div id="inside-content-post">

    <div class="post-grad">
      <div class="text-post-title">
        personal 2 </div>
      <div class="text-post">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rutrum eros non vestibulum ullamcorper. Aliquam arcu justo, pretium non ullamcorper in, egestas nec leo. Duis vulputate nisi at orci facilisis, vitae mollis arcu pretium. Morbi faucibus,
          urna sit amet pulvinar imperdiet, magna ante vulputate lectus, facilisis mattis dolor sapien aliquam magna. Suspendisse cursus bibendum ante sit amet rutrum. Curabitur condimentum ultrices justo, at dapibus augue malesuada in. Etiam auctor nulla
          in ex pulvinar accumsan. Maecenas blandit nisl sit amet risus luctus ornare. Donec semper pretium diam vel faucibus.</p>
        <p>Curabitur a vehicula ligula. Morbi tristique ullamcorper malesuada. Cras lacus quam, semper mattis neque sit amet, lacinia tristique turpis. Aliquam vitae facilisis magna, vel lacinia orci. Pellentesque ut erat mauris. Morbi blandit nisl vitae
          nisl sodales iaculis. Ut eget tortor a orci iaculis venenatis. Duis in interdum nisi. Duis egestas, mi sit amet egestas consequat, justo mi vehicula neque, sollicitudin fringilla risus quam at lectus. Donec dictum mauris id porta euismod. Morbi
          congue velit a justo tincidunt ultrices. Proin viverra faucibus risus in sagittis. Quisque auctor, sem ultrices mollis ultricies, sem nisi lacinia dolor, vitae condimentum felis mauris vel mi.</p>
        <p>Aenean vestibulum, leo nec consequat bibendum, justo magna mollis augue, eget tempor nibh sapien vitae nisi. Maecenas nec ligula eros. Nullam efficitur lacus sed semper venenatis. Curabitur iaculis congue enim nec convallis. Donec vulputate id
          massa placerat auctor. Donec feugiat convallis lectus id hendrerit. Quisque commodo, dui a porta porta, nulla justo vestibulum sem, vitae efficitur odio mi eu nibh. Curabitur maximus, dolor eu pulvinar suscipit, arcu magna sollicitudin nulla,
          at aliquam odio tellus sit amet sem. Curabitur at ultricies sapien. Nullam id nibh dui. Nullam mattis pharetra sodales. Aliquam vestibulum eget elit at hendrerit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
          mus. In odio quam, pellentesque eget bibendum ornare, bibendum vel lectus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what it's actually meant to be doing? When I run the snippet, clicking on the project button expands (animates) a black box behind the text, clicking on it again just collapses the black box

Comment: The text should follow

Comment: So the text should always stay below the black box in the white area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also add transition to this class `.text-post` that you are also animating and then it will also work with overflow hidden. You can also simplify you jQuery code by only using toogleClass:

```js
jQuery('#post-button').click(function() {

  jQuery(this).toggleClass('open-button');

  jQuery(".post-content, .post-grad, .text-post").toggleClass("open-post");


});
```

```css
.post-content {
  height: 0vh;
  width: 80%;
  background: #464646;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-post {
  color: blue;
  font-family: Avenir_Light;
  height: 0vh;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-post-title {
  color: white;
  font-family: Avenir_Light;
  height: 0vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-grad {
  width: 80%;
  height: 0vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72));
  position: fixed;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}

.open-post {
  height: 80vh;
}

#post-button {
  display: inherit;
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#post-button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#post-button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#post-button span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0px;
}

#post-button.open-button span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="post-button">
  <span></span>
  <span></span> Project Button
</div>
<div class="post-content">
  <div id="inside-content-post">

    <div class="post-grad">
      <div class="text-post-title">
        personal 2 </div>
      <div class="text-post">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rutrum eros non vestibulum ullamcorper. Aliquam arcu justo, pretium non ullamcorper in, egestas nec leo. Duis vulputate nisi at orci facilisis, vitae mollis arcu pretium. Morbi faucibus,
          urna sit amet pulvinar imperdiet, magna ante vulputate lectus, facilisis mattis dolor sapien aliquam magna. Suspendisse cursus bibendum ante sit amet rutrum. Curabitur condimentum ultrices justo, at dapibus augue malesuada in. Etiam auctor nulla
          in ex pulvinar accumsan. Maecenas blandit nisl sit amet risus luctus ornare. Donec semper pretium diam vel faucibus.</p>
        <p>Curabitur a vehicula ligula. Morbi tristique ullamcorper malesuada. Cras lacus quam, semper mattis neque sit amet, lacinia tristique turpis. Aliquam vitae facilisis magna, vel lacinia orci. Pellentesque ut erat mauris. Morbi blandit nisl vitae
          nisl sodales iaculis. Ut eget tortor a orci iaculis venenatis. Duis in interdum nisi. Duis egestas, mi sit amet egestas consequat, justo mi vehicula neque, sollicitudin fringilla risus quam at lectus. Donec dictum mauris id porta euismod. Morbi
          congue velit a justo tincidunt ultrices. Proin viverra faucibus risus in sagittis. Quisque auctor, sem ultrices mollis ultricies, sem nisi lacinia dolor, vitae condimentum felis mauris vel mi.</p>
        <p>Aenean vestibulum, leo nec consequat bibendum, justo magna mollis augue, eget tempor nibh sapien vitae nisi. Maecenas nec ligula eros. Nullam efficitur lacus sed semper venenatis. Curabitur iaculis congue enim nec convallis. Donec vulputate id
          massa placerat auctor. Donec feugiat convallis lectus id hendrerit. Quisque commodo, dui a porta porta, nulla justo vestibulum sem, vitae efficitur odio mi eu nibh. Curabitur maximus, dolor eu pulvinar suscipit, arcu magna sollicitudin nulla,
          at aliquam odio tellus sit amet sem. Curabitur at ultricies sapien. Nullam id nibh dui. Nullam mattis pharetra sodales. Aliquam vestibulum eget elit at hendrerit. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
          mus. In odio quam, pellentesque eget bibendum ornare, bibendum vel lectus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```